# \operatorname in amsmath: polish diacritic letters "ł" and "Ł" are not rendered

Tags: fonts, amsmath

I am attempting to use a mathematical operator (by `amsmath` package) which would use the polish letter "ł" or "Ł" (defined either directly as a UTF-8 character or via the `\l{}`, `\L{}` commands). Unfortunately, this does not work (the minimal non-working example below) and the letter "ł" is simply not displayed properly.

Defining a new operator via `\DeclareMathOperator` gives the same issue.

So: how to use / define mathematical operators which would contain the letters "ł" or "Ł"?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fontencoding{T1}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is what I like:
\L{}uk
\l{}uk
Łuk

Unfortunately, I see here only uk instead of łuk:
\[ \operatorname{\L{}uk} 
\operatorname{\l{}uk}
\operatorname{Łuk}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Accented letters are not allowed in math mode as you will see in the log. You might want to try `\operatorname{\textup{\L{}uk}}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I don;t think `lmodern` is related to this.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi without `LaTeX Warning: Command \L invalid in math mode on input line 15` in the log? Note the OP is not asking for `\L` in the text but used to name a math operator.

Comment: `\usepackage{lmodern}` works fine for the minimal non-working example from the original question. However, my original (non-minimal) problem concerned a document with class `\documentclass{beamer}` where `\usepackage{lmodern}` does not work. In this setup the second solution `\operatorname{\textup{\L{}uk}}` works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument of `\operatorname` is typeset in the “operator font” that uses the OT1 encoding, where no `\L` character is available, but only plain ASCII letters. Changing it to be T1-encoded would make it harder to use Greek uppercase letters.

When you run your example, you see three warnings

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \L invalid in math mode
LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode
LaTeX Warning: Command \L invalid in math mode
```

You may want to define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\textoperatorname}[1]{%
  \operatorname{\textnormal{#1}}%
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\textoperatorname}[1]{%
  \operatorname{\textnormal{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
This is what I like:
\L{}uk
\l{}uk
Łuk

\[
\textoperatorname{Łuk}
\textoperatorname{łuk}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\l` or `\L` instead of `ł` or `Ł` is immaterial.

Comment: This solution works fine also with `\documentclass{beamer}` class, opposite to the solution with `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bounded to `Latin Modern`, there's no problem with `Fourier`, as it uses `T1-encoding` for maths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Luk}{Łuk}
\DeclareMathOperator{\luk}{łuk}
\begin{document}
This is what I like:
\L{}uk
\l{}uk
Łuk

Fortunately, with \emph{Fourier} I see here what I want:
\[ \operatorname{\L{}uk}\quad
\operatorname{\l{}uk}\quad
\operatorname{Łuk}\quad
\Luk\quad\luk
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oops! Didnt check the contents of my clipboardmanager! Thank you for pointing the problem. It's corrected now.

Comment: The package `erewhon` seems to be rather new and is not included in popular distributions (it is available in Debian sid, but not in Ubuntu 14.04). I removed it, and your example works fine.  However, this solution does not work with the `beamer` class of the document.

Comment: It's been here for more than a year. It is the successor of `heuristica`, which you may have. Both are an extension of `Adobe Utopia`, on which Fourier is based. They add true small caps, superior and inferior figures, cyrillic, greek and arabic.